# trying to checking a value within in a form is a number in a set range

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, numbers, range

Trying to write a script that will check the value in the form is a number between the range of 1 to 99999.

1)      The script work mostly except for two things if you put a number then letter it won’t detect that you entered letters as well as numbers

2)      I want it to run the script on onblur event, however every time I try the script does not work at all.

Did study java years and year ago and found I forgotten most things if people can point out where I am going wrong would be very greatful

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Please enter your age</title>
<script language="JavaScript1.2">
function checknumber(){
var x=document.checknum.pnum.value
/*does it contain non digits */
var anum=/(^\D+$)|(^\D+\.\D+$)/
if (anum.test(x))
{
alert("Please input a valid Runner ID between 1 to 99999 !")
testresult=false
}
/*is it above 99999*/
else if (x > 99999)
{
alert("Please input a valid Runner ID between 1 to 99999 !")
testresult=false
}
/*is it below 1*/
else if (x < 1)
{
alert("Please input a valid Runner ID between 1 to 99999 !")
testresult=false
}
return (testresult)
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="checknum" onSubmit="return checknumber()">
Please input a valid Runner ID between 1 to 99999:
<input type="text" name="pnum" onchange="checknumber()">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Many Thanks
Damien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import Jquery Library and use this function

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){    
$("#pnum").keypress(function (e)  
{ 
  //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
  if( e.which!=8 && e.which!=0 && (e.which<48 || e.which>57))
  {
    return false;
  } 
});
});
```

but id for the textbox

```
 <input type="text" name="pnum" id="pnum" maxLength="5" >
```

this will ensure that you can add numbers only and 5 char

Comment: JQuery Library put this code in the <head> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>

Comment: HI thanks for the reply do I add that to my existing code  or replace it tried replacing it but nothing happens cheers

Comment: also need t5o make sure the value entered is not zero guess I can do if ele else options

Comment: love jquery thaks all for the help